# Drupal debug (know which file are used)

Tags: 7

I need to modify something in a website (it's a form in the backoffice), the problem is that I don't know where is it located in the files, I try to search some words of the form with phpstorm but nothing.

Is there a way to activate something like a debug who can show which files are used to show the current page ?

Comment: That's called a backtrace, the best way to see it is to use a proper debugger. PHPStorm makes this [very, very easy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Lookup the ID in the form]

Have a look at the id of the form. In my screenshot it says 'user-login-form'. If the form you are looking for is written in code (a custom module), you should find something when searching for 'user_login_form' (notice the difference: underscores instead of dashes)

Comment: This is a good starting point but the relationship of form ID to the form callback is not always so simple. The module name will almost always be used as a prefix in the ID, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Theme debug mode**

As of Drupal 7.33, Drupal core has a theme debug mode that can be enabled and disabled via the theme_debug variable. Theme debug mode can be used to see possible template suggestions and the locations of template files right in your HTML markup (as HTML comments). To enable it, add this line to your settings.php:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

You can enable it with drush using:

```
drush vset theme_debug 1
```

And disable using

```
drush vset theme_debug 0
```